# Get the used port of a print job

Tags: c#, .net

I try to create a print job monitor similar to the build-in windows version.

My current problem is that I'm not able to get the information of the specific port on which the print job gets printed.

I used `System.Printing` as well as `ManagementObjectSearcher` querying `Win32_PrintJob`.

None of them providing this information.

Answer (score 0):

The **System.Printing** namespace and the **Win32_PrintJob** class in ManagementObjectSearcher do not provide direct access to the specific port on which a print job gets printed. You can try this approach to gather this information.
You can use the **System.Printing** namespace to enumerate the printer ports and retrieve the information about the ports associated with the printers. For example:

```
using System.Printing;

// Get the collection of local printers
LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueueCollection printQueues = printServer.GetPrintQueues();

// Iterate through the print queues and retrieve the printer ports
foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in printQueues)
{
    string printerName = printQueue.Name;
    string printerPort = printQueue.QueuePort.Name;

    // Use printerName and printerPort as needed
}
```

Comment: I already tried this. But with this approach only delivers the available ports for the printer/queue, not the port of a specific printjob on which is going to print.

Comment: Printjobs do not have a specific port. When a print job is submitted, it is added to the print queue, and the print spooler handles the task of sending the job to the appropriate printer device.